# ASP.Net MVC C# with Toastr not minifing javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 - and attempting to use Toastr too.

I installed it via NuGet - and it works in development, however, when I publish, my Javascript "bundle" reports:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(9908,1-2): run-time warning JS1002: Syntax error: }
 */
/*!
* jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.3
* http://jquery.com/
```

My bundle file is:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace BootstrapSupport
{
public class BootstrapBundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.1.js",
            //"~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js",
             "~/Scripts/toastr.js",
            "~/Scripts/mt.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/body.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-mvc-validation.css",
             "~/Content/style.css",
             "~/Content/toastr.css"

            ));
    }
}
}
```

If I take Toastr out from the bundle above, everything else works fine.

Any idea how I can resolve this problem please?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Hi - this isn't a fix, but a workaround - if I copy the code from toastr.js into the toastr.min.js file - then it works - so it appears there may be a difference between the two files (other than one being minified of course!!)

Comment: The behavior you are observing when you rename it to toastr.min.js is because the Bundling & Minification component has the convention of not minifying files that with the pattern *.min.js. That's why you do not see the error come up. It just outputs the file content as is.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like toastr has some syntax error like missing semicolon, that is affecting the minification process. Here are two things you can try:

1. Check if there is a newer version of toastr.
2. Pass the file through http://www.jslint.com or http://jshint.com/ and see what it reveals.

Update:
I tried to reproduce your problem with toastr v1.3.1 (downloaded via NuGet) but did not encountered any issues.